# how to validate date format using regular expression

Tags: regex, date-format

I want to verify if the date provided is in the correct format. It doesn't matter if the date is correct or not. I am only interested in the format. And, I don't how to handle it. Here is the regular expression that I am using

My complete expression is .+(\b[0-9]?\b).+(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})

but the date part is

(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})

This works good if the date is 07/02/2011 but it doesn't work if the date is 7/2/2011

I tried (\d{1-2}/\d{1-2}/\d{4})

but that didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following (It replaces the dashes with commas):

```
\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Since, you replied first I am accepting your answer otherwise Wooble answer is also correct. I have spent lot of time but couldn't find the comma thing :) Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for a range of lenths in a regular expression is `{1,2}`, not `{1-2}`.

```
(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})
```

Answer (score 0):

For dd-mm-yyyy format, use
`^([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.]([1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$`
further info can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html).